# Computer Permissions issue with React Native, Expo, Axios

Tags: react-native, axios, expo

Inside React Native with Axios I'm making a request using axios to a remote url. I keep getting this error if I try to make the request.

```
The file “Macintosh HD” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.
```

Here's some of my code:

```
// inside componentDidLoad()

ExampleService.index().then(response => {
  console.log('service response: ',response);
})
```

```
// in side ExampleService.js
function index() {
  return client({
    url:    `/`,
    method: 'GET'
  });
}
```

```
// inside client

const client = axios.create({
  baseUrl: 'http://192.168.42.64:3000',
  headers: {
    // 'Authorization': authHeader,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
});
```

Comment: I worked around this by just using fetch directly in the component, but I would like to use the more abstract "service" pattern.